# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error. App not able to route to different pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the above error. I just started a Angular Project, and this isnt exactly my first rodeo, but I've never received this error before.

Below is my html and JS code with the include statements. Am I missing a script, or am I initializing my module incorrectly?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Examples of Exploits</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class = "container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Exploit Examples</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/!">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!sqlInjection">SQL Injection</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/",{
        templateUrl : index.html
    })
        .when("/sqlInject", {
            templateUrl:sqlInjection.html
        });
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>` and put `"sqlInjection.html"` and `"index.html"` in quotes and `'ngRoute'` in `var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);`

I have made an example on codepen which may help you https://codepen.io/Ferhad/project/editor/DGgPKb#

Comment: Your solution is giving me an infinite loop that causes JQuery to crash.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to inject `ngRoute` in your app. You can do it like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

And don't forget to include script for `angular-route`, for example from here (But you better use a local version!):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
```

And I don't see, where you are importing your script with defining app module and routes, looks like you forgot to include it in your HTML too.

Comment: @jsauder81, I have updated the answer. Didn't you forget to include `angular-route.js` script?

Comment: Still have the same issue.

Comment: @jsauder81, looks like you forgot to include your file with angularjs code in your HTML too, I have updated the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle based on @CommercialSuicide answer.

Here is fiddle.

I think this problem occurred by missing `'` in templateUrl.

Try this.

https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/osvjc8mb/

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/",{
        templateUrl : 'index.html'
    })
    .when("/sqlInject", {
        templateUrl: 'sqlInjection.html'
    });
}])
```